# gradle publishing project-version-PLAIN.war file instead of project-version.war

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, artifactory

When I run "gradle build", it generates a build/libs/project-version.war file which is able to run by itself with "java -jar" command. But when I run "gradle artifactoryPublish", it saves on the artifactory repository a "project-version-plain-war" file which does not have tomcat embedded.

I am following this instruccions https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Gradle+Artifactory+Plugin

The lines added to the gradle.build are something like this:

```
plugin "maven-publish"
plugin "com.jfrog.artifactory"
artifactory { 
...
}

subprojects {
  plugin "war"
  group = group
  version = version

  publishing {
    publications {
      MavenPublication(MavenPublication) {
        from components.web
      }
    }
    repositories{
      maven { url "https://artifactory-server" }
    }
  }
}
```

help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `from components.web` means that you are publishing the artifact produced by the `war` task. You need to publish the artifact produced by the `bootWar` task. You can do so by changing the publication to use `artifact bootWar` instead:

```
publishing {
  publications {
    MavenPublication(MavenPublication) {
      artifact bootWar
    }
  }
  repositories{
    maven { url "https://artifactory-server" }
  }
}
```

This is described in the [reference documentation for Spring Boot's Gradle plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.x/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#publishing-your-application.maven-publish).

Comment: Thanks a lot! that's the answer C: